# Why is Jcrop "onRelease" not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcrop

so basically the problem is that Jcrop's onRelease is not working for me? Here is a part of the code

```
$('#target').Jcrop({
  aspectRatio: 9 / 16,
  minSize: [minCropWidth, minCropHeight ],
  onChange: updatePreview,
  onSelect: updatePreview,
  onRelease: cropIt
},function(){
```

...

```
function cropIt(){
    console.log("The onRelease function");
}
```

So, the "updatePreview" function works like a charm, but, the "cropIt" does nothing. Can't even get a console.log(); to show.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the `cropIt` function already declared when the `.Jcrop(...)` function executes? If `cropIt` is still `null` there, this would explain the behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that you misunderstood the behaviour of the `onRelease` method?

Lets have a look this simplified [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tbu8m/), with the browsers console opened:

The image is loading fine and you can select a part of the image that you want to crop.
Your console is logging a lot of

```
[Log] The updatePreview function (show, line 43)
[Log] The updatePreview function (show, line 43, x34)
[Log] The updatePreview function (show, line 43)
[Log] The updatePreview function (show, line 43)
```

`updatePreview` calls, since it is called whenever you change the selection.

Now you stop your selection, and probably expect `onRelease` to trigger.
But this is not happening. Why?

`onRelease` triggers when you let go your selection, hence clicking anywhere on the image *outside* of your selection will trigger it.

`[Log] The onRelease function (show, line 39)`

`onRelease` means you cancel your selection, not to stop dragging your crop indicator.

Comment: So that's the solution to my problem! :).. I always thought that on release is when I release the croping area, and that's that. Thank you for clearing that out!

Comment: what is the purpose of onRelease? when does it get called?